# Gmail API Python Quickstart gmail-python-quickstart.json: No such file or directory

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, gmail-api

I'm trying to execute this example here: Step 3 @  [Gmail API Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)
I got two errors and got aroudn them

1. Unable to unintsall a exisiting version of six - got around by setting it to

   `--ignore-installed six`
2. Unable to find httplib2 - got around by doing a specific

   `pip2 install httplib2`

Now when I go the working directory where my `client_secret.json` & `quickstart.py` are located and execute a `python quickstart.py` I get the follwoing error. Any ideas how to get this code to execute.

```
bash-3.2$ python quickstart.py 
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py:255: UserWarning: Cannot access /Users/Zafar/.credentials/gmail-python-quickstart.json: No such file or directory
  warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 73, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart.py", line 57, in main
    credentials = get_credentials()
  File "quickstart.py", line 45, in get_credentials
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/tools.py", line 218, in run_flow
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1934, in step1_get_authorize_url
    return _helpers.update_query_params(self.auth_uri, query_params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 222, in update_query_params
    parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(uri)
AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlparse'
```

Comment: first uninstall `six` python3 - pip3 uninstall six, python2 - pip uninstall six and then reinstall

Answer (score 1):

I've just faced the same problem.
You need to create the file and name it gmail-python-quickstart.json.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know.